# After change from Ubuntu to Lubuntu the mouse wheel (scroll) doesn't work without pressing CTRL together

Tags: mouse, scrolling

When I try to scroll with mouse I receive a message saying `Wrong type argument: commandp, mouse-5` or `Wrong type argument: commandp, mouse-4`. This happens after I tried a lot of random fixes. Before the message was something like `C-M-)` and `C-M-(` is undefined.

But... If I press CTRL while mouse scrolling, it works fine as expected.

How can I fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Emacs in a terminal?

Comment: Emacs GUI. I tried to use on Emacs -nw and when I tried to scroll I got it: (((((((())))))                                                                                    
  ((((((((((((())))                                                                               
           )))))))))))

Comment: Have you tried running Emacs without your init file? (`emacs -q`)

Comment: Yes. But I get the message `C-M-)` (scroll down) and `C-M-(` (scroll up). I was trying solution in this post: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36024/mouse-wheel-not-working-with-new-mouse without success in my init file. Here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36024/mouse-wheel-not-working-with-new-mouse#comment56803_36036 I discovered that if I press CTRL everything works fine.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `C-h l` right after you used the wheel?

Comment: If I use Emacs GUI I obtain: https://pastebin.com/yz3wYNYR and if I use `emacs -nw` (terminal) I get: https://pastebin.com/czyMLDCq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be helpful, but I have the following in my init file to fix a scroll-wheel issue on Lubuntu. I was using an older Logitech mouse at the time. You'll probably have to adjust `<mouse-11>/<mouse-12>`.

```lisp
(when (and (string= system-name "foo"
           (window-system))
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-11>") (kbd "<mouse-4>"))
  (global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-12>") (kbd "<mouse-5>")))
```

OP EDIT (the final code, in my case, that fits my original question):

```lisp
;; Fix mouse wheel
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-(") (kbd "<mouse-4>"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-)") (kbd "<mouse-5>"))
```

Comment: You can probably get it to work slightly more reliably if you use `(define-key function-key-map (kbd "<mouse-11>") (kbd "<mouse-4>"))` instead of `global-set-key`.